# Site Blocker for Mobile Safari Google Searches

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile-safari, safari-extensions

Is there a way to block content scraper sites from Google searches on Mobile Safari?  I would like something like the "Personal Blocklist" now available for Google Chrome.

Comment: I just hope google implements it on google.com itself, at very least while we're logged in!

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Safari does not support browser extensions, which is what powers the block list.

We may see something in the future, but you're out of luck until then.

Comment: Almost nothing more can be said for now... Even considering jailbreaking I doubt there's anything out there that goes that far.